# Methods , Smaller value

Tags: java, methods, selection, output

i have a task to write a program that take two integers and print the smaller value integer using an method called Min i did it like the following code its working perfectly , but my question is i cant figure  out how to include a massage or condition when the inputs are equal
from the user .

Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class Min

 { 

        public static void main(String[]args)

        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");
            int fnumber = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");
            int snumber = in.nextInt();
            int result = min(fnumber,snumber);
            System.out.println(result + " Has the smaller Value ");
        }

        public static int min (int n1, int n2)

        {

            if (n2 < n1)
            {
                return n2;
            }

            else
            {
                return n1;
            }


        }  

}
```

Comment: Why is your method that determines the minimum called `max`?

Comment: `if (fnumber == snumber) { //insert statements` make sure to include a `}` after it. See the [If Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: sorry , because i had one for bigger values , edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
if (n2 == n1)
 {
     System.out.println(result + " The values are equals! ");
     return -1;
 }

 else if (n2 < n1)
 {
     return n2;
 }
 else
 {
     return n1;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works the best so far , like this i can display the massage " The values are equals! " then that -1 has the smaller value , any idea how to stop the massage " has the sammler value " from displaying  if the numbers are equal? thx a lot

Comment: Sure you can just do a an if (result != -1) before displaying the message.
if (result != -1)
{
System.out.println(result + " Has the smaller Value ");
}

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition in your max method for checking the equality.  Here is the codition you need to add to your max method.

```
if(n2 == n1){
   System.out.println("Numbers are equal");
   return 0; // or any other logical number
}
```

Comment: How will this compile? The method expects an `int` to be returned.

Comment: Do not add the above codeline inside MAX method... add this codeline inside Main function , just before calling max function. this will cause problem because you are returning 0 and inside main function.. it will print (0 is the smallest).

Comment: thx , i was geting a complier error  about missing return statement . now it works but the message from my main method will be printed like this anyway and i get the value 0 also

Answer (score 0):

You can return -1 to show that both inputs are equal. This would work only if you have non negative numbers as input. Else return either one of them

```
public static int max (int n1, int n2)

{
    if(n2==n1)
    {
        return -1;
        // OR return n1;
        // OR return n2;

    }
    if (n2 < n1)
    {
        return n2;
    }

    else
    {
        return n1;
    }


}
```